# Installed Perl modules not available

Tags: perl, cpan

On CentOS 6.2, perl v5.10.1 and I cannot install XML::SAX::Expat. Using "cpan XML::SAX::Expat"

a lot of the earlier problems I solved (there were a lot more errors when I first tried to installl XML::Simple) came from missing binaries required by the cpan config (in my case: unzip, make, lynx, patch, gcc, ftp). Since this is the only module failing to install (all other prerequisites are already installed), I am under the impression that I already installed all the OS requirements (via yum). **Am I correct to assume this?**

BTW, the histfile doesnt get created. **Which permissions should i apply to /root/.cpan/ ?**

**What should I try next? Is it ok to force install?**

```
All tests successful.
Files=13, Tests=486, 12 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.01 sys +  1.84 cusr  0.07 csys =  1.99 CPU)
Result: PASS
  GRANTM/XML-Simple-2.20.tar.gz
Tests succeeded but one dependency not OK (XML::SAX::Expat)
  GRANTM/XML-Simple-2.20.tar.gz
  [dependencies] -- NA
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 TODDR/XML-Parser-2.41.tar.gz                 : make NO
 BJOERN/XML-SAX-Expat-0.40.tar.gz             : make_test NO
 GRANTM/XML-Simple-2.20.tar.gz                : make_test NO one dependency not OK (XML::SAX::Expat)
```

Output from cpan conf:

> load_module_verbosity [v]
>
> lynx               [/usr/bin/lynx]
>
> make               [/usr/bin/make]
>
> make_arg           []
>
> make_install_arg   []
>
> make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make]
>
> makepl_arg         [INSTALLDIRS=site]
>
> mbuild_arg         []
>
> mbuild_install_arg []
>
> mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
>
> mbuildpl_arg       [--installdirs site]
>
> ncftp              []
>
> ncftpget           []
>
> no_proxy           []
>
> pager              [/usr/bin/less]
>
> password           undef
>
> patch              [/usr/bin/patch]
>
> patches_dir        undef
>
> perl5lib_verbosity [v]
>
> prefer_installer   [MB]
>
> prefs_dir          [/root/.cpan/prefs]
>
> prerequisites_policy [ask]
>
> proxy_pass         undef
>
> proxy_user         undef
>
> randomize_urllist  undef
>
> scan_cache         [atstart]
>
> shell              [/bin/bash]
>
> show_unparsable_versions [0]
>
> show_upload_date   [0]
>
> show_zero_versions [0]
>
> tar                [/bin/tar]
>
> tar_verbosity      [v]
>
> term_is_latin      [1]
>
> term_ornaments     [1]
>
> test_report        [0]
>
> trust_test_report_history [0]
>
> unzip              [/usr/bin/unzip]
>
> urllist
>
> ```
> 0 [ftp://cpan.pair.com/pub/CPAN/]
>
> 1 [ftp://ftp-mirror.internap.com/pub/CPAN/]
>
> 2 [ftp://cpan.cs.utah.edu/CPAN/]
>
> 3 [ftp://mirror.atlantic.net/pub/CPAN/]
>
> 4 [http://httpupdate19.cpanel.net/CPAN/]
> ```
>
> use_sqlite         [0]
>
> username           undef
>
> wait_list          undef
>
> wget               [/usr/bin/wget]
>
> yaml_load_code     [0]
>
> yaml_module        [YAML]

Comment: One more dependency to install with `yum`: `expat` and/or `expat-devel`?

Comment: Please [don't use XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have [yum](http://yum.baseurl.org/) available, then run

```
yum install expat
```

and

```
yum install expat-devel
```

Comment: You should install libvirt-devel before you can build the cpan module.

Answer (score 2):

For debian distribution install libxml-sax-expat-incremental-perl then install XML::Simple module from CPAN

```
sudo apt-get install libxml-sax-expat-incremental-perl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
make clean XML::Simple

Comment: pls see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198431/installed-perl-modules-not-available/45209462#comment77385968_11198431

Answer (score 0):

For Debian distributions one can also install XML::Simple directly:

```
apt-cache search XML::Simple | grep simple
apt-get install libxml-simple-perl
perl -MFile::Find=find -MFile::Spec::Functions -Tlw -e 'find { wanted => sub { print canonpath $_ if /\.pm\z/ }, no_chdir => 1 }, @INC' 2> /dev/null | grep -i xml/simple
```

Comment: pls see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198431/installed-perl-modules-not-available/45209462#comment77385968_11198431